# Cleaning Large Volume Of String Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project where I have a large list of raw retailer tenant names with some basic stats like Total Gross Leasing Area (GLA). But there are variations in some of the tenant names so a clean up exercise is required. I know I have seen different solutions online with text comparison using levensthein. I have started to use the Wratio and UQRatio functions from the fuzzywuzzy module.

My current method is to have two For loops to iterate through every two tenant combinations to compare each tenant name with every other possible tenant name. If the Harmonic average of the two string names is >80% then I consider them to be a match. My assumption is to always take the string for the tenant with the largest GLA, thus I first sort my tenant list by this metric prior to iterating through the list. Below is my current code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd


#create list of tenants sorted by Number of Locations and Total Gross Leasing Area. Use this for For Loop
tenant_list = df.sort_values(by=['Num_Of_Locations','Total_GLA'], ascending=False).Tenant_Name.to_list()

tenant_1_list=[]
tenant_2_list=[]
ratio_list=[]
iteration_list=[]



#create initial df_lookup dataframe to use for first iteration in For Loop (i.e. for first tenant_1)
tenant_1 = tenant_list[0]
for tenant_2 in tenant_list[1:]:
    tenant_1_list.append(tenant_1)
    tenant_2_list.append(tenant_2)
    ratio_list.append(0)
    iteration_list.append(0)
      
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame(zip(iteration_list,tenant_1_list,tenant_2_list,ratio_list,tenant_1_list,tenant_2_list), columns=['Iteration','Tenant_1','Tenant_2','Ratio','Tenant_1_Cleaned','Tenant_2_Cleaned'])    


#create empty list to use for concatenating dataframes
df_list=[]

#boolean to use for first tenant
first=True
i=1
for tenant_1 in tenant_list[0:len(tenant_list)-1]:
#create empty lists
    tenant_1_list=[]
    tenant_2_list=[]
    tenant_1_cleaned_list=[]
    tenant_2_cleaned_list=[]
    ratio_list=[]
    iteration_list=[]
    
#If/Else Block below is used to set tenant_1_cleaned for the iteration in the outer For Loop. If it is not the first iteration, 
#then we need to look in the df_lookup dataframe to see if this Tenant_1 string was mapped to a "Tenant_2_Cleaned" that differs from "Tenant_2" in a prior Tenant_1 vs Tenant_2 comparison
    if(first):
        tenant_1_cleaned=tenant_1
        first=False
    else:
        tenant_1_cleaned = df_lookup.loc[df_lookup.Tenant_2==tenant_1].drop_duplicates(subset=['Tenant_2'],keep='last')['Tenant_2_Cleaned'].unique()[0]      
        
    
    #Loop through all tenants after tenant_1 to run fuzzy comparison
    for tenant_2 in tenant_list[i:]:
        #append tenant1,tenant2 and tenant_1_cleaned values to respective lists
        tenant_1_list.append(tenant_1)
        tenant_2_list.append(tenant_2)
        tenant_1_cleaned_list.append(tenant_1_cleaned)        

    
        #check if tenant_2 has been mapped to a tenant_2_cleaned value in previous For Loop iterations. If so, take that value. Want that value to pervail throughout
        tenant_2_cleaned = df_lookup.loc[df_lookup.Tenant_2==tenant_2].drop_duplicates(subset=['Tenant_2'],keep='last')['Tenant_2_Cleaned'].unique()[0]
        
        #compute a score of string similarity between tenant_1 and tenant_2
        harmonic_value=0                
        s1 = fuzz.WRatio(tenant_1,tenant_2)
        s2 = fuzz.UQRatio(tenant_1,tenant_2)
        
        #Compute harmonic average. Need to check if s1 or s2 are greater than 0 to prevent division by 0 in harmonic average calc
        if (s1>0) or (s2>0):
            harmonic_value = 2*s1*s2 / (s1+s2)

            #Check if string similarity score is greater than 80 AND that tenant_2 has not been mapped previously. If condition is TRUE then goal is to set Tenant_2_Cleaned to equal Tenant_1_Cleaned. So append Tenant_1_Cleaned to tenant_2_cleaned_list
            #Else just use the tenant_2_cleaned value that was set earlier in this inner for loop
            if (harmonic_value>80) & (tenant_2_cleaned==tenant_2):
                tenant_2_cleaned_list.append(tenant_1_cleaned)
            else:
                tenant_2_cleaned_list.append(tenant_2_cleaned)
        else:
            tenant_2_cleaned_list.append(tenant_2_cleaned)

        #append the ratio score to use for validation in future steps
        ratio_list.append(harmonic_value)        
        #append the counter for the outer loop iteration number
    iteration_list.append(i)
        
    #use lists to create dataframe for the outer loop iteration
    df_lookup_latest = pd.DataFrame(zip(iteration_list,tenant_1_list,tenant_2_list,ratio_list,tenant_1_cleaned_list,tenant_2_cleaned_list), columns=['Iteration','Tenant_1','Tenant_2','Ratio','Tenant_1_Cleaned','Tenant_2_Cleaned'])
    
    #Update df_lookup by adding new results from current iteration
    df_list.append(df_lookup_latest)
    df_lookup=pd.concat(df_list)
    df_lookup=df_lookup.sort_values(by=['Iteration'])
    i=i+1        


#Reduce dataframe to the last records for each Tenant_2 and the respective Tenant_2_Cleaned string. This represents the final required mapping
df_lookup['Tenant2'].drop_duplicates(subset=['Tenant_2'],keep='last')['Tenant_2','Tenant_2_Cleaned']
```

Below is a visual of how the code would work with a small set of tenant names. In this example there are 5 string variations for Macys.

| Tenant Name | GLA |
| --- | --- |
| Abercrombie | 100 |
| MACYS | 90 |
| MACY S | 80 |
| MACY'S | 70 |
| GAP | 60 |
| MACYSS | 50 |
| MACYSSS | 40 |

My logic would process the following tenants in the The ratio numbers below are not accurate but filled them in to illustrate the logic

| Iteration | Tenant_1 | Tenant_2 | Ratio | Tenant_1_Cleaned | Tenant_2_Cleaned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abercrombie | MACYS | 0.1 | Abercrombie | MACYS |
| 1 | Abercrombie | MACY S | 0.1 | Abercrombie | MACY S |
| 1 | Abercrombie | MACY'S | 0.1 | Abercrombie | MACY'S |
| 1 | Abercrombie | GAP | 0.1 | Abercrombie | GAP |
| 1 | Abercrombie | MACYSS | 0.1 | Abercrombie | MACYSS |
| 1 | Abercrombie | MACYSSS | 0.1 | Abercrombie | MACYSSS |
| 2 | MACYS | MACY S | 0.95 | MACYS | MACYS |
| 2 | MACYS | MACY'S | 0.92 | MACYS | MACYS |
| 2 | MACYS | GAP | 0.05 | MACYS | GAP |
| 2 | MACYS | MACYSS | 0.85 | MACYS | MACYSS |
| 2 | MACYS | MACYSSS | 0.8 | MACYS | MACYSSS |
| 3 | MACY S | MACY'S | 0.95 | MACYS | MACYS |
| 3 | MACY S | GAP | 0.05 | MACYS | GAP |
| 3 | MACY S | MACYSS | 0.92 | MACYS | MACYS |
| 3 | MACY S | MACYSSS | 0.88 | MACYS | MACYSSS |
| 4 | MACY'S | GAP | 0.05 | MACYS | GAP |
| 4 | MACY'S | MACYSS | 0.92 | MACYS | MACYSS |
| 4 | MACY'S | MACYSSS | 0.88 | MACYS | MACYSSS |
| 5 | GAP | MACYSS | 0.02 | GAP | MACYS |
| 5 | GAP | MACYSSS | 0.02 | GAP | MACYSSS |
| 6 | MACYSS | MACYSSS | 0.92 | MACYS | MACYSSS |

My code works but it seems to be slow and I am going to be running this across thousands of different tenant names. Any suggestions on how to optimize this? Thank you

Comment: You might want to use [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) instead of FuzzyWuzzy, which is significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you implementing this. Looks to be well documented too. It looks like the portion that is causing the longest slowest is occuring when I am setting tenant_1_cleaned and tenant_2_cleaned with these formulas: tenant_1_cleaned = df_lookup.loc[df_lookup.Tenant_2==tenant_1].drop_duplicates(subset=['Tenant_2'],keep='last')['Tenant_2_Cleaned'].unique()[0]   AND 
 """tenant_2_cleaned = df_lookup.loc[df_lookup.Tenant_2==tenant_2].drop_duplicates(subset=['Tenant_2'],keep='last')['Tenant_2_Cleaned'].unique()[0]"""

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple lines of the numpy.where function.
E.g. for Macy's and assuming your dataframe is called df

```
    df["tenant_1_cleaned"] = np.where(df["tenant_1"].str.startswith("MAC"),"MACYS", df["tenant_1"])
    df["tenant_2_cleaned"] = np.where(df["tenant_2"].str.startswith("MAC"),"MACYS", df["tenant_2"])
```

Comment: I can't hard code text specifically to clean for variations of Macys. There are other tenant names that will have varying strings in my dataset for example, I may have GAP and BABY GAP.

Comment: Instead of `.str.startswith` use `.str.contains` and then use regex to pattern match

Comment: It looks like the actual string comparison is not very slow but the issue is when I am continuing to do the concat and sort. Any other approach that I could do to solve for that?